# Getting the top N sorted elements from a data.frame in R for large dataset

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe, plyr

I am relatively new to R, so this maybe a simple question. I tried searching extensively for an answer but couldn't find one.

I have a data frame in the form:

```
firstword  nextword   freq
a          little     23
a          great      46
a          few        32
a          good       15
about      the        57
about      how        34
about      a          48 
about      it         27
by         the        36
by         his        52
by         an         12
by         my         16
```

This is just a tiny sample for illustration from my data set. My dataframe is over a million rows. firstword and nextword are character type. Each firstword can have many nextwords associated with it, while some may have only one.

How do I generate another dataframe from this such that it is sorted by desc. order of freq for each 'firstword' and contains only the top 6 nextwords at most.

I tried the following code.

```
small = ddply(df, "firstword", summarise, nextword=nextword[order(freq,decreasing=T)[1:6]])
```

This works for smaller subset of my data, but runs out of memory when I run it on my entire data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dplyr` package is created for this purpose to handle large datasets. try this

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(firstword) %>% arrange(desc(Freq)) %>% top_n(6)
```

Comment: Worked great! Wouldn't have thought of it. Thanks

Comment: As David's answer notes, it might be faster to do your `arrange` before the `group_by`. (joran's edit above put this Q&A in my stackoverflow feed. Whoops, just noticed how old it is.)

Answer (score 5):

Here's a similarly efficient approach using the `data.table` package.
First, you don't need to arrange `freq` in *every* group, sorting in only once is enough and more efficient. So one way would be simply

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[order(-freq), .SD[seq_len(6)], by = firstword]
```

another way (possibly more efficient) is to find the indexes using the `.I` argument (**I**ndex) and then to subset

```
indx <- df[order(-freq), .I[seq_len(6)], by = firstword]$V1
df[indx]
```